# AppCenter bash script to change the Version Name in Android Manifest file

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

I created a CI CD in AppCenter for my Android app made with Xamarin Forms and I'm trying to change the Version Name in the Manifest file with a custom script.
I tried some approaches, mainly from [this post from Montemagno](https://montemagno.com/vs-app-center-custom-build-scripts-for-production-apps/) but with no success.

I have seen the use of this `BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH` and `APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY` variables in the script, tried both and didn't work.

My manifest file is located in this path: `src/Dashview.Mobile/Dashview.Mobile.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml`

and my script is like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Updating Manifest

MANIFEST="$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/src/Dashview.Mobile/Dashview.Mobile.Android/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml"

VERSIONNAME=`grep versionName ${MANIFEST} | sed 's/.*versionName\s*=\s*\"\([^\"]*\)\".*/\1/g'`

sed -i.bak "s/android:versionName="\"${VERSIONNAME}\""/android:versionName="\"1.0.${APPCENTER_BUILD_ID}\""/" ${MANIFEST}

rm -f ${MANIFEST}.bak

# Print out file for reference
cat $MANIFEST

echo
```

The script is located in the root of the Xamarin.Android project and is a pre-build with a name appcenter-pre-build.sh

In the generated log, I can't see that the manifest was changed with the cat command, it gets recognized by AppCenter because I can see the Pre-build badge but it's like not being executed because my App is always in the 1.0.0 version.

If anybody has done something like this, I'll appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I am having the same issue where App Center shows the Pre-Build script badge but I am not seeing any of the echo lines being output to the log and my release number is not changing.

Comment: @Filosopher My problem was because the bash script was created in Windows and I needed to create that on a Mac machine (because of the line breaks if I'm not mistaken)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here [Version Name change example in script](https://github.com/Microsoft/appcenter/blob/master/sample-build-scripts/xamarin/version-name/appcenter-pre-build.sh) ? There are also some other examples how to change values in AndroidManifest.xml using pre-build scripts.

Regarding your folder directory issue. If you have a Xamarin Android project, so I would assume you need to use

```
$APPCENTER_SOURCE_DIRECTORY/YourDroidProjectName/Properties/AndroidManifest.xml
```